# Web console says my JSON is invalid

Tags: json

I am working on a data visualization using Raphael.js, JavaScript and JSON. The data is stored in a JSON file that Firefox keeps saying is invalid in the first line. I have checked the JSON file in two validators and each time Firefox keeps saying the first line is incorrect. The JSON consists of an array with an object and a nested array. Below is a sample of the code:

```
{ "XXXXXX" : [ { "abbrev" : "XXX",
    "XXX" : "XXXXXXX",
    "XXX" : [ { "XXX" : "XXXXX",
          "XXX" : "XXXXX",
          "XXX" : "XXXXXXX"
        },
        { "XXX" : "XXXX",
          "XXX" : "XXXXXXX%XXXXXXX",
          "XXXX" : "XXXXX"
        },
        { "XXX" : "XXXXX",
          "XXX" : "XXX%XXXXXXXX",
          "XXXX" : "XXXXXX"
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

Comment: That JSON is definitely invalid. What's the question?

Comment: First opening parenthesis is unmatched. Copy&paste error?

Comment: Repeated keys. A simplification artifact as well?

Answer (score 1):

USE this code :

```
var jsonId ={ "XXXXXX" : [ { "abbrev" : "XXX",
        "XXX" : "XXXXXXX",
        "XXX" : [ { "XXX" : "XXXXX",
              "XXX" : "XXXXX",
              "XXX" : "XXXXXXX"
            },
            { "XXX" : "XXXX",
              "XXX" : "XXXXXXX%XXXXXXX",
              "XXXX" : "XXXXX"
            },
            { "XXX" : "XXXXX",
              "XXX" : "XXX%XXXXXXXX",
              "XXXX" : "XXXXXX"
            }
          ]
      }
    ]}
```